# Duplicate submission issue since first journal never responded to submission or withdrawal

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I submitted my research article to journal A earlier. They neither responded to my submission nor sent me any confirmation of my submission. I mailed them for the withdrawal of our submission. They did not respond to that email either. By that time I decided to submit my research to another journal B, which  published my paper. The problem arose as journal A sent me an email regarding the acceptance of my submission.
What should I do now to overcome this situation? Will it be considered as duplicate submission?

Answer (score 9):

Remind them of the previous communications and insist that you already withdrew the paper. Provide copies if possible, with dates.

No, it isn't a duplicate publication, but make sure they understand that their "acceptance" is moot. It isn't required that your withdrawal be acknowledged for it to take effect since the rights to the paper are/were still yours.

I hope it isn't a case of your emails being sent to the wrong address and lost somehow. It would take some effort to clear that up. They might have been acting in good faith in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I later found my mail was blocked in first case (The email to journal). Then I have mailed their publisher as well (No response from them either). Probably they changed their previous email address (which is the case I assume).

Comment: I think the default assumption should be that the first journal is acting in good faith. It certainly sounds like a lot of time passed—a predatory journal would presumably have acted faster (and with a request for money).

Comment: @GregMartin, In this case, should I offer to submit a revised and developed version of my research work (I am currently working on it), and let the editor know about the issue? Will there be any consequences for this issue? I am a little confused about what should I do now.

Comment: @GregMartin On the other hand, I find it very unusual that a non-predatory journal accepts a first submission without any changes required from the reviews. At least in my field.